# JavaScript addEventListener windows.onload organization

Tags: javascript, onload, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

Sorry if this is an obvious question, I'm just getting frustrated.  Why doesn't this work?  Note that the js file is referenced in the header, which is why I use the window.onload function.

```
window.onload = function() {
    x = document.getElementById("something");
    x.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
};
```

Also note that the getElementByID code works just fine.  I disabled the element with it, no problem.

Comment: What does not work ?

Comment: Does this code execute after all the page content has loaded?  What is the element?

Comment: Take a look at my code here: [https://jsfiddle.net/1s192nrv/](https://jsfiddle.net/1s192nrv/) - this seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Because it works fine here : https://jsbin.com/nepovex/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It must be caused by something else on your page because the code is fine.

Comment: Working now, don't know why.  I think it was just a naming mismatch that I was oblivious to, sorry.  I'm going to delete this question in a few minutes as it is not educational.  The code was in the header, and the element was a form text input.

Answer (score 0):

All major browsers support **addEventListener** method. Excepts IE 8 and earlier, you have to use **attachEvent** method.

For cross-browser solution:

```
window.onload = function() {
  let x = document.getElementById("fthis");
  if(x.addEventListener){
    x.addEventListener("click", yourFunction);
  }
  else if(x.attachEvent){
    x.attachEvent("onclick", yourFunction);
  }
```

It may be a problem.